# How to get an interactive bash shell in a Docker container

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to connect to a running container or start a new container in interactive mode with the bash shell -- not the sh shell. I want to run:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash
```

or

```
docker run -it <container_name> <image_name>
```

or

```
docker run -it <container_name> <image_name> /bin/bash
```

and get an interactive bash shell.

### What I've tried so far:

Per [this post](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7281#issuecomment-389440503) I've tried

#### Adding this to my Dockerfile

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

#### Adding this to my Dockerfile

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo I am now using bash!"]
```

But every time I try to run a container in interactive mode (`docker run -it` or attach to a running container (`docker exec -it`), I land in the `sh` shell.

How can I get an interactive bash shell that is running inside a docker container?

#### Update: Minimal working Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Comment: Have a full Dockerfile (or, rather, one complete enough to constitute a [mcve], but no larger than the shortest possible thing that achieves that goal)? Not every container *has* a copy of bash at all; unless we know what you're deriving `FROM`, or if you're taking explicit steps to install bash where appropriate, we can't say if yours does or not.

Comment: BTW, what output *do* you get from `RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo \"$BASH_VERSION\""]`? You say you tried the relevant `RUN`, but you don't tell us what happened.

Comment: How did you determine that the shell you ended up in was `sh`?

Comment: I figured it is the sh shell by appearance (white plain text vs. the green boldface text that you normally see in the bash terminal in ubuntu) and the fact that I am unable to repeat the previous command by pressing the up arrow key, etc. Also, I updated with a minimal working Dockerfile.

Comment: What does `echo $BASH_VERSION` outputs in the shell you think is `sh`?

Comment: Ahh. Bash itself doesn't give you a green boldface prompt out-of-the-box, that's just something your distro sets up for you as part of the default account template (which of course doesn't propagate into containers). And your container isn't ever *expected* to have access to your host's history.

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSION` outputs `4.4.20 (1)-release`. Looks like you're right, I am in a bash shell.

Comment: I realized that the issue with the arrow keys is that I am accessing a docker container  over ssh, and it is similar to this question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/163802/backspace-tab-del-and-arrow-keys-not-working-in-terminal-using-ssh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in fact running an interactive bash with commands like:

```
docker container run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

When you run bash in a docker container, that shell is in a container. So it won't have the command history from outside of the container, that history is maintained on the host filesystem. It also won't have your prompt, the `PS1` variable is not automatically exported into the container's environment. And it won't have your `.bashrc` configuration from your host, since that isn't inside the container. Instead you get a bash shell that is out of the box from a minimal ubuntu host.